# How to create FragmentStatePager with multiple custom fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm creating a FragmentStatePager that include a fragment list (ArrayList).
But the exception's saying "**The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first**".
Please check my codes.

Here is **my_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svMyFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is the adapter.

```
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int noOfPages;
private List<MyFragment> myFragmentList;

public SlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<MyFragment> fragmentList){
    super(fm);
    myFragmentList = fragmentList;
    noOfPages = fragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return myFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return noOfPages;
}}
```

I make some fragments for testing and put them in a FragmentList and simply initiate the adapter.

```
public class PagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static SlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;
int pageTotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_slide);

    ArrayList<MyFragment> fragmentList = getFooFragmentList();
     // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new SlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    pageTotal = mPagerAdapter.getCount();
    mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

private ArrayList<MyFragment> getFooFragmentList() {
    final ArrayList<MyFragment> fooFragmentList = new ArrayList<MyFragment>();
    MyFragment fooFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(produceALayout("Inside first fragment"));

    fooFragmentList.add(fooFragment);
    MyFragment fooFragment2 = MyFragment.newInstance(produceALayout("Inside second fragment"));
    fooFragmentList.add(fooFragment2);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Submit");
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyFragment myFrag = null;
            for(int i=0; i<fooFragmentList.size()-1; i++){
                myFrag = fooFragmentList.get(i);
                LinearLayout lL = myFrag.getLinearLayout();
                for(int j=0; j<lL.getChildCount(); j++){
                    String name = lL.getChildAt(j).getClass().getName();
                    Log.i("class name : ", name);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(button);
    MyFragment submitFragment = MyFragment.newInstance(linearLayout);
    fooFragmentList.add(submitFragment);
    return fooFragmentList;
}

private LinearLayout produceALayout(String label){
    LinearLayout lL = new LinearLayout(this);
    lL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    lL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 70);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setText(label);
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(lp);
    editText.setHint(label);
    lL.addView(tv);
    lL.addView(editText);
    return lL;
}}
```

When I run , it seems works when swiping left to right.
But the problem become when I swipe back (right to left).
It is saying "**The specified child has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first**". I don't know where to remove view and I don't want to do it.
Because when the user click submit, I need to get every data from each fragment user typed.
That's why I can't remove any view. Do you have any better way to do so?